# Crystal Reports Split Function within the Color Function

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field in a DB called option1 which holds RGB values like the following;

255.255.5
255.255.1 etc

I need my Crystal Report to read this field and change the color of a box. I tried the following;

color (Split({ac.option1}, ".")[1],Split({ac.option1}, ".")[2],Split({ac.option1}, ".")[3])

color (255,255,5) clearly works but this is giving me an error stating a number is required.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Ash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the results of the Split() function to numbers:

```
Color( ToNumber(Split({ac.option1}, ".")[1]), ToNumber(Split({ac.option1}, ".")[2]), ToNumber(Split({ac.option1}, ".")[3]) )
```

Comment: @craig, is there more to this formula than what meets the eye?  I'm trying to do this and I'm receiving an error message "A subscript must be betwen 1 and the size of the array."  I copied the code and only changed the field name.  My data is stored as: 0,191,255  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Change the formula to use commas instead of periods.